# how to change time format to 24hrs? in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
    Literal four = new Literal();
    string timeanddate;
    timeanddate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    DateTime dt_calc = new DateTime();
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(timeanddate);
    dt_calc = dt.AddHours(3);
    four.Text = "3hr added and this gives>>  " +  dt_calc.ToString();
    form1.Controls.Add(four);
```

its all in AM PM i want to work with 24hrs

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for every way you could possibly want to format a `DateTime`.

Note that you use "HH" for 24-hour time.

For example, if you wanted the format "23:00:00" instead of "11:00:00 PM" you would use:

```
string formatted = dt_calc.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

By the way, your initialization of your `DateTime` values with `new DateTime()` is unnecessary.

Comment: okay but, is there a way to make the 24hrs default, that is what if i donot want to use any formatting options! just the value returned by default should be 24 hrs.

Comment: @user287745: Yes, there is! First see [jgauffin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536789/how-to-change-time-format-to-24hrs-in-c/3537366#3537366); then, for more information, see: [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) and [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the current culture.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(1053);
string swedishTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); //24h format

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(1033);
string englishTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); //am/pm format
```

Comment: Sounds like this would be a change for the whole app. What if you want to do this per logged in user? I.e. based on the `Accept` header for example, so it is locale based?

Comment: This is indeed system-wide, typically done in desktop applications. For web-based applications, I would only serve UTC date/time in culture invariant formats. Let the front-end format and convert to local time.

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but here is the syntax from above with string interpolation:

```
string formatted = $"{dt_calc:HH:mm:ss}";
```